# Custom .net component not firing from within Biztalk Expression Shape

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have a test Biztalk project with an Orchestration containing a couple of Receive shapes, Send Shapes, and an Expression Shape.  The Expression shape makes a call to a referenced dll that was written in C#.  The C# dll is in the GAC, the class is marked as Serializable and the class has only one static method that is supposed to create a file on the disk in a folder.

Everything builds and deploys, but when I kick off the Orchestration by placing a file in the Receive folder, all the shapes do what they are supposed to do EXCEPT for the Expression shape.  The code definitely works as I have tested it locally and the directory is one that the BT app is already accessing, so I don't think it is a security issue.

Below is the C# code and below that is how I am calling the code from the Expression shape, can anyone offer any suggestions as to what is going wrong?:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace TestHelp
{
    [Serializable]
    public class TestWrite
    {
        public static void CreateFile()
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Unrecorded\Out\DataForProcess\Test.txt");
            fi.Create();

        }
    }
}
```

Expression Shape code:

```
TestHelp.TestWrite.CreateFile();
```

Comment: Catch any exceptions and write them to the event log.

Comment: Tried that, didn't log anything because I don't think the dll is getting instantiated.  It seems that Biztalk is just ignoring the Expression shape.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess I'd say probably that BizTalk is picking an older copy of the orchestration dll. Are you sure you updated it on the GAC or re-deployed before trying? Other than that, easiest way to find out what's going on is to just attach a debugger to the BizTalk instance (BTSNTSvcs.exe) and try to debug it... you could easily check this way if indeed your C# assembly is getting loaded and executed.

Comment: Before debugging BTSNTSvcs.exe I'd try out Orchestration Debugger because your guess that an older version of the Orchestration gets executed.